# Proof of Generalized Riemann Integrability Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose f:[a,b] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function and there is a set Z $\subset$ [a,b] sucht that:

1. f is continuous at every point x $\notin$Z.
2. For every $\epsilon$ > 0, the set Z can be covered by finitely many intervals with total length less than $\epsilon$.

Show that f is Riemann integrable on [a,b]

Have no idea how to handle this proof? Any hints or suggestions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy -- It seems to be only a special case of Lebesgue's Criterion, as the the covers of the set $Z$ are **finite** in the OP's formulation, whereas a set of Lebesgue measure zero allows countable, infinite covers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Once you cover Z by a set U which is a union of **open** intervals of total length $<\epsilon$,  f is uniformly continuous on $[a, b] - U$.